# How to choose the order of variable elimination in bayes net?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian-networks

I have the following bayes net with me.

[image]

I want to find `P(+h|+e)`. So I have to find `A = P(+h,+e)` and `B = P(+e)` to find `P(+h|+e)`. I wanted to follow variable elimination for find the probability. Taking different orders is giving me different probabilities. How should I choose my order of the variable elimination for accurate calculation of `P(+h|+e)`?

1. Will it be okay if I calculate P(+h,+u,+e) and eliminating +u instead of finding P(+i, +h, +t, +u, +e) and eliminating +i,+t and +u for finding P(+h,+e)?
2. How do I calculate P(+e)?

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence arguably off-topic here; better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.P(h|e) is the conditional probability of P(cause | effect ),we are using an effect to infer the cause (diagnostic direction).
P(c| e)P(e) /P(c) = P(h| e)P(e)/P(h) = P(h,e)P(e)/P(h)
So to calculate P(h,e) you would have to calculate joint distribution with all the variables and marginalise each one since they are relevant to the query and evidence variables.
P(+i, +h, +t, +u, +e) would be the correct choice

2. To calculate P(+e) we would need only its parents, i.e Good test taker and understands the material. So we need to calculate the underlying conditional distribution P(e| t,u) and marginalizing out the variables t, u.

P(+e) 
= Sum_t( Sum_u( P(+e, t, u))) 
= P( +e | +t,+u)P(+t)P(+u) + P( +e | +t,-u)P(+t)P(-u) +  P( +e | -t,+u)P(-t)P(+u)+  P( +e | -t,-u)P(-t)P(-u)